# How to make all possible changes of bit of codeword?

Tags: matlab, binary, linear-algebra

I want to understand this sentence.

'' for `1<=f<=4`, make all possible changes of `f` of the `k` bits of codeword `v`.''

Example :

```
if k = 4 and v = [1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
```

for me we obtain :

```
for f = 1 : u1 = [1 0 0 0] ; u2 =[0 1 0 0]; u3 = [0 0 1 0] and u4 =[0 0 0 1];
for f = 2 : u2 = [1 1 0 0] ; u2 =[1 1 0 0]; u3 = [1 0 1 0] and u4 =[1 0 0 1]; 
u5 = [0 1 1 0]; u6 = [0 0 1 1];
for f = 3 : u1 = [1 1 1 0]; u2 = [1 1 0 1]; u3 = [1 0 1 1] and u4 = [0 1 1 1];
for f = 4 : u1 = [1 1 1 1];
```

Anyone have any other way of understanding this sentence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` is the number of bits in `v`. `f` is the number of bits to be changed. The question, to me, boils down to:

Show all variations of `v` that have `k-f` bits in common with `v`

for example, for `f = 4, v = [0,0,0,0,0]` we would obtain:

```
v = [1,0,0,0,0]
v = [0,1,0,0,0]
v = [0,0,1,0,0]
v = [0,0,0,1,0]
v = [0,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Thanks@Owen Hempel for your idea. But, if we know the value of `v`, that contains `7` bits for example. With your idea what result should be obtained? for `1<=f<=4`, make all possible changes of `f` of the `4` bits of codeword `v`.

Comment: well, what you're saying is that `k = 7`. Do you need a working code solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd like to help you but you won't learn by copy-pasting my code. Besides, this is a relatively simple algorithm. Just try to think through what you need to calculate. If you find yourself writing the same lines of code several times, try to condense it into a function.